# How to install Swift on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: swift, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I want to install Swift on Raspberry Pi 3 model B. Rasberry Pi is running with Ubuntu mate 15.10 but I have errors when I write swift this I see  in terminal

> install a package "python-swiftclient"

when I install this package and write "swift" it couldn't find this command.

So any suggestions ?

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.0 is available for the Raspberry Pi 2 and 3.  You can download and install it from the instructions at http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/swift-3-0-on-raspberry-pi-2-and-3/.

Disclaimer:  I host this site, but am a part of a larger community bringing Swift to ARM-based devices.  See http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/swift-for-arm-systems/ for details on joining our Slack community.

Answer (score 3):

The official Swift site only has binaries for x64 processors. If you want to install on Pi3, look at the resources from iachieved.it or uraimo. They have lots of tips on compiling and using Swift on Pi, as well as binaries for all Pi versions.

Answer (score -2):

Swift is not distributed via default Ubuntu package manager. That means that you can't install by using `apt-get install`. What you need to do is download the compiled Swift package from [swift.org](https://swift.org) website. First run wget to get the Swift package in `.tar.gz` compressed file.

```
$ wget https://swift.org/builds/swift-2.2-release/ubuntu1510/swift-2.2-RELEASE/swift-2.2-RELEASE-ubuntu15.10.tar.gz
```

Then you need to unarchive the file by running

```
$ tar xzf swift-2.2-RELEASE-ubuntu15.10.tar.gz
```

This will unarchive the file and create folders where binaries are located. Go to `swift-2.2-RELEASE-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin/` and check that `swift` binary exists. You can run it by typing this into your terminal window.

```
$ ./swift
```

Comment: Apple is currently only releasing binaries for x86.  The OP asked specifically about binaries that would run on the Rasperry Pi 3 which is an ARM-based processor, thus whether or not one could install via `apt-get` vs. `tar xzf` is irrelevant.